# How to test 500.html in rails development env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

I want to test the 500 error pages in my Rails app using the development environment.

I already tried this in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

But this does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Would changing your environment to Production help?

Comment: I personally think that it's better to switch to the production env for testing error pages. If you always disable Rails's built-in error pages in development, you could be making it more difficult to see valuable debugging information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either:

1. access the application using address other than localhost or 127.0.0.1 which rails considers by default to be local requests
2. Override `local_request?` in `application_controller.rb` to something like:

> ```
> def local_request?
>   false
> end
> ```

The second will stop rails treating requests from localhost and 127.0.0.1 as local requests which combined with `consider_all_requests_local = false` should show you your 500.html page.

Comment: For those coming from Google and using Rails 3, look to the next answer.

Answer (score 85):

The only way I've found to do this so far is to set in `development.rb`

`config.consider_all_requests_local = false`

Now, restart the server.

Then access the URLs using my local IP address: `http://192.168.1.135:3000/blah`

The other settings mentioned don't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Also works in Rails 4. BTW, it works for me also using either 127.0.0.1:3000/page_which_does_not_exist or localhost:3000/page_which_does_not_exist

Comment: Does not work for me. I'm getting no route matches instead of internal server error.

Comment: After setting config.consider_all_requests_local = false don't forget to restart the server.

Answer (score 30):

None of the proposed solutions worked in my Rails 3 app. The quick and dirty solution for me was to simply hit the error pages directly to see the rendered HTML. For example,

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/404.html

http://0.0.0.0:3000/500.html
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I'm getting the 500 error page but I'm seeing it being logged by the rails server or the development log.

Answer (score 24):

Just do a http://localhost:3000/404 or /500 to access these pages and see how they look like.

Comment: This is the shortest and best answer for someone who just wants to test design for those pages

Answer (score 9):

In addition to setting:

`config.consider_all_requests_local = false`

I also needed to set:

`config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true`

Comment: Note that this should be set before server start and has no effect afterwards  (= may not be suitable for auto testing where you need both behaviours)

Answer (score 4):

You should add the below lines to the application_controller,

```
unless  ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_500
    if  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_404
    end
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :render_404
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_404
end
```

Then try running with the below settings.

`config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false` in **config/environments/development.rb:**

It will work. Please dont forget to write the function in **application_controller.rb** to render the layout for each of the error messages.

Comment: You could also just use the `rescue_from` directive at the top of the controller, as in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-default-500-and-404-templates

Comment: ActionController::UnknownAction doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper setting to twiddle is this:

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs = false
```

Why it's still labelled `rjs` isn't entirely clear.

Comment: this doesn't have any effect for me either

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to force a 500 error to see what it looks like, you can just add this to a view:

haml example:

```
= render :partial => "broken", :status => 500
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue