# How to handle routing error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing the routing error if the route is not match. I want to redirect the page to 404 static page if the route not match.
I used some references but it's not working.
The following error is displayed when No route matches.
No route matches [GET] "/userss"

Rails.root: D:/Ruby/Assignment/Library

Comment: You will get it (no route matches ....) on development environment  but no on production environment, if you want to render 404 try read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156490/how-to-test-500-html-in-rails-development-env

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your routes.rb file write

```
  get      '*path'       => redirect('your path of static page')
```

Answer (score -2):

Add these lines in your `application_controller.rb`

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404

private

def render_404
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", status: 404 }
    format.json { render json: { status: 404, message: 'Page Not Found' } }
  end
end
```