# How to turn off the red/grey error help page tool in rails development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I'm trying to replicate a bug in development which come from the production environment.

When the bug occurs I should see a 500 server error, but rails is displaying the following page to me, which is not what I want:

[the grey rails error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j8Qy.png)
(the error in the image is not the one I'm trying to reproduce, but it shows they error page, which is what I'm talking about here)

How can I turn off this feature from rails so it just display a 500 error that a normal user will see?

And what is this tool/page called? I usually just call it the (red) rails error page. (but in this case it is grey for some reason, I don't know why too. Does anyone know?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156490/how-to-test-500-html-in-rails-development-env

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: The question of the post you linked helped me. I selected the answer for my post (this). The solution is indeed as simple as changing "consider_all_requests_local: true" to "consider_all_requests_local: false"

Comment: Glad to hear you got it all working :-)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the link, learned a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to the following

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

By default, this value is `true` because of the need to `debug` code on development environment that's why, if you change value with `false` then will show the error page which is designed default.

If you need to generate and design custom then the follow this [tutorial](http://blog.salahsoftwaresolution.com/generate-dynamic-error-page-rails/).

Hope to help

Answer (score -1):

What about run rails in production environment?

```
rails server -e production
```

Comment: I try to use production but got adapter problem so I use my dev DB as my prod DB and that problem go away. Then I try to access the page and I got routing error. Some style sheet seems to be not working. I'm looking for a way to simply turn off that red rails error page and see what a normal user will see.